# UITextView delegate never called

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextview delegate `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView` that is never getting called and I have been struggling with this for a couple of days to no avail.  Here is what I have

I have declared the `<UITextViewDelegate>` in my header file and in ViewDidLoad I am setting the delegate, I have tried `self.myTextView.delegate = self;`
and `myTextView.delegate = self;` along with wiring up the delegate in the NIB file instead of declaring it programmatically.

I have a few custom buttons that insert the text into my UITextView by 2 different methods depending on the button, the first method here is...

```
-(IBAction)string1:(id)sender {

NSRange range = myTextView.selectedRange;  
NSString * firstHalfString = [myTextView.text substringToIndex:range.location];  
NSString * secondHalfString = [myTextView.text substringFromIndex: range.location];  
myTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;  

NSString * insertingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert my text string"];

myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@",  
                 firstHalfString,  
                 insertingString,  
                 secondHalfString];  
range.location += [insertingString length];  
myTextView.selectedRange = range;  
myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;}
```

and the second method is ...

```
-(IBAction)string2:(id)sender {

myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"my other string value"];}
```

With NSLog turned on, I can see that

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
 NSLog(@"something changed");}
```

does get called but this delegate never gets called

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
NSUInteger newLength = (textView.text.length - range.length) + text.length;
if(newLength <= MAX_LENGTH)
{
    return YES;
} else {
    NSUInteger emptySpace = MAX_LENGTH - (textView.text.length - range.length);
    textView.text = [[[textView.text substringToIndex:range.location] 
                      stringByAppendingString:[text substringToIndex:emptySpace]]
                     stringByAppendingString:[textView.text substringFromIndex:(range.location + range.length)]];
    return NO;
}
NSLog(@"something else changed");}
```

At the top of my .M file I have defined `#define MAX_LENGTH 100`

Any help would be very much appreciated, my overall goal is to limit the number of charters in the UITextView.

Comment: One first note, you won't see `NSLog(@"something else changed");`because both `if` and `else` do a `return` before they get there. :-)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, I had the logging prior to the returns but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` only sends `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` to its delegate in response to user events.  It does not send that message when your program sets the `myTextView.text` property.

I'm surprised that the `UITextView` is sending `textViewDidChange:` to the delegate, since [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006897-CH3-SW7) says "This method is not called in response to programmatically initiated changes."

So, you could clip the text in `textViewDidChange:` instead (and rely on its behavior being different from the documentation), or modify and `string1:` and `string2:` to clip the text.

Comment: you definitely helped me out pointing me in the right direction.  I have chosen to limit the textview input by doing this 
`if (myTextView.text.length >= 10)
    {
     myTextView.text = [myTextView.text substringToIndex:10];
    }
    
    NSLog(@"limit reached");`